# How to solve Front controller reached 100 router match iterations in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have installed Magento 2 in the server, my front end works fine and the back end shows error as the Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

```
a:4:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:3968:"#0 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#6 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#17 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#18 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Here is my custom module Router.php

```
actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_authorFactory = $authorFactory;
        $this->_tagFactory = $tagFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    /**
     * Validate and Match Blog Pages and modify the request
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return bool
     */
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $_identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $_identifier = urldecode($_identifier);

        $pathInfo = explode('/', $_identifier);
        $blogRoute = $this->_url->getRoute();

        if ($pathInfo[0] != $blogRoute) {
            return;
        }
        unset($pathInfo[0]);

        if (!count($pathInfo)) {
            $request
                ->setRouteName('blog')
                ->setControllerName('index')
                ->setActionName('index');
        } elseif ($pathInfo[1] == $this->_url->getRoute(Url::CONTROLLER_RSS)) {
            $request
                ->setRouteName('blog')
                ->setControllerName(Url::CONTROLLER_RSS)
                ->setActionName(isset($pathInfo[2]) ? $pathInfo[2] : 'index');
        } elseif ($pathInfo[1] == $this->_url->getRoute(Url::CONTROLLER_SEARCH)
            && !empty($pathInfo[2])
        ) {
            $request
                ->setRouteName('blog')
                ->setControllerName(Url::CONTROLLER_SEARCH)
                ->setActionName('index')
                ->setParam('q', $pathInfo[2]);
        } elseif ($pathInfo[1] == $this->_url->getRoute(Url::CONTROLLER_AUTHOR)
            && !empty($pathInfo[2])
            && ($authorId = $this->_getAuthorId($pathInfo[2]))
        ) {
            $request
                ->setRouteName('blog')
                ->setControllerName(Url::CONTROLLER_AUTHOR)
                ->setActionName('view')
                ->setParam('id', $authorId);
        } elseif ($pathInfo[1] == $this->_url->getRoute(Url::CONTROLLER_TAG)
            && !empty($pathInfo[2])
            && $tagId = $this->_getTagId($pathInfo[2])
        ) {
            $request
                ->setRouteName('blog')
                ->setControllerName(Url::CONTROLLER_TAG)
                ->setActionName('view')
                ->setParam('id', $tagId);
        } else {
            $controllerName = null;
            if (Url::PERMALINK_TYPE_DEFAULT == $this->_url->getPermalinkType()) {
                $controllerName = $this->_url->getControllerName($pathInfo[1]);
                unset($pathInfo[1]);
            }

            $pathInfo = array_values($pathInfo);
            $pathInfoCount = count($pathInfo);

            if ($pathInfoCount == 1) {
                if ((!$controllerName || $controllerName == Url::CONTROLLER_ARCHIVE)
                    && $this->_isArchiveIdentifier($pathInfo[0])
                ) {
                    $request
                        ->setRouteName('blog')
                        ->setControllerName(Url::CONTROLLER_ARCHIVE)
                        ->setActionName('view')
                        ->setParam('date', $pathInfo[0]);
                } elseif ((!$controllerName || $controllerName == Url::CONTROLLER_POST)
                    && $postId = $this->_getPostId($pathInfo[0])
                ) {
                    $request
                        ->setRouteName('blog')
                        ->setControllerName(Url::CONTROLLER_POST)
                        ->setActionName('view')
                        ->setParam('id', $postId);
                } elseif ((!$controllerName || $controllerName == Url::CONTROLLER_CATEGORY)
                    && $categoryId = $this->_getCategoryId($pathInfo[0])
                ) {
                    $request
                        ->setRouteName('blog')
                        ->setControllerName(Url::CONTROLLER_CATEGORY)
                        ->setActionName('view')
                        ->setParam('id', $categoryId);
                }
            } elseif ($pathInfoCount > 1) {
                $postId = 0;
                $categoryId = 0;
                $first = true;
                $pathExist = true;

                for ($i = $pathInfoCount - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                    if ((!$controllerName || $controllerName == Url::CONTROLLER_POST)
                        && $first
                        && ($postId = $this->_getPostId($pathInfo[$i]))
                    ) {
                        //we have postId
                    } elseif ((!$controllerName || !$first || $controllerName == Url::CONTROLLER_CATEGORY)
                        && ($cid = $this->_getCategoryId($pathInfo[$i], $first))
                    ) {
                        if (!$categoryId) {
                            $categoryId = $cid;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $pathExist = false;
                        break;
                    }

                    if ($first) {
                        $first = false;
                    }
                }


                if ($pathExist) {
                    if ($postId) {
                        $request
                            ->setRouteName('blog')
                            ->setControllerName(Url::CONTROLLER_POST)
                            ->setActionName('view')
                            ->setParam('id', $postId);
                        if ($categoryId) {
                            $request->setParam('category_id', $categoryId);
                        }
                    } elseif ($categoryId) {
                        $request
                            ->setRouteName('blog')
                            ->setControllerName(Url::CONTROLLER_CATEGORY)
                            ->setActionName('view')
                            ->setParam('id', $categoryId);
                    }
                } elseif ((!$controllerName || $controllerName == Url::CONTROLLER_POST)
                    && $postId = $this->_getPostId(implode('/', $pathInfo))
                ) {
                    $request
                        ->setRouteName('blog')
                        ->setControllerName(Url::CONTROLLER_POST)
                        ->setActionName('view')
                        ->setParam('id', $postId);
                }
            }
        }

        $condition = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'identifier' => $_identifier,
                'request' => $request,
                'continue' => true
            ]
        );
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'magefan_blog_controller_router_match_before',
            ['router' => $this, 'condition' => $condition]
        );

        if ($condition->getRedirectUrl()) {
            $this->_response->setRedirect($condition->getRedirectUrl());
            $request->setDispatched(true);
            return $this->actionFactory->create(
                'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect',
                ['request' => $request]
            );
        }

        if (!$condition->getContinue()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!$request->getModuleName()) {
            return null;
        }

        $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $_identifier);

        return $this->actionFactory->create(
            'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
            ['request' => $request]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve post id by identifier
     * @param  string $identifier
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getPostId($identifier, $checkSufix = true)
    {
        return $this->getObjectId(
            $this->_postFactory,
            Url::CONTROLLER_POST,
            $identifier,
            $checkSufix
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve category id by identifier
     * @param  string $identifier
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getCategoryId($identifier, $checkSufix = true)
    {
        return $this->getObjectId(
            $this->_categoryFactory,
            Url::CONTROLLER_CATEGORY,
            $identifier,
            $checkSufix
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve category id by identifier
     * @param string $identifier
     * @param bool $checkSufix
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getAuthorId($identifier, $checkSufix = true)
    {
        return $this->getObjectId(
            $this->_authorFactory,
            Url::CONTROLLER_AUTHOR,
            $identifier,
            $checkSufix
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve tag id by identifier
     * @param string $identifier
     * @param bool $checkSufix
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getTagId($identifier, $checkSufix = true)
    {
        return $this->getObjectId(
            $this->_tagFactory,
            Url::CONTROLLER_TAG,
            $identifier,
            $checkSufix
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param $factory
     * @param string $controllerName
     * @param string $identifier
     * @param bool $checkSufix
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getObjectId($factory, $controllerName, $identifier, $checkSufix)
    {
        $key =  $controllerName . '-' .$identifier . ($checkSufix ? '-checksufix' : '');
        if (!isset($this->ids[$key])) {
            $sufix = $this->_url->getUrlSufix($controllerName);

            $trimmedIdentifier = $this->_url->trimSufix($identifier, $sufix);

            if ($checkSufix && $sufix && $trimmedIdentifier == $identifier) { //if url without sufix
                $this->ids[$key] = 0;
            } else {
                $object = $factory->create();
                $this->ids[$key] = $object->checkIdentifier(
                    $trimmedIdentifier,
                    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                );
            }
        }

        return $this->ids[$key];
    }

    /**
     * Detect arcive identifier
     * @param  string  $identifier
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isArchiveIdentifier($identifier)
    {
        $info = explode('-', $identifier);
        return count($info) == 2
            && strlen($info[0]) == 4
            && strlen($info[1]) == 2
            && is_numeric($info[0])
            && is_numeric($info[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are using a custom module? if yes the Controller/Router.php file of the module seems to be in an endless loop

Comment: this means your controller path not found
like $this->getUrl('routename/controllerlocpath/conrollername') not found.

Can you share all code like xml , controller.

Comment: I have attached my custom module Router.php, plz check it

Comment: I am new to magento2 , so plz tell me the path of the files

Comment: If you disable this module then everything works fine?

Comment: No , I thing the issue is with cms module Router.php?